# Incorrect Arrary subscripts

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <cmath>
 class Base
 {
   protected:
     int n;                                               // Allocate the dynamic memory.
     typedef double Coord[2];
     Coord* city_location;

     Base(int ncities) : n(ncities), city_location(new Coord[n]) {}
     ~Base() { delete [] city_location; }
 };



 template <class T> class Map;

 struct Flat;
 template <> class Map<Flat> : public Base
 {
   public:                                                   // Setting up the map in the flat euclidean version.

Map(int n) : Base(n)
{
  double Path[n];
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    city_location[i][0] = (static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX))*80;
    city_location[i][1] = (static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX))*80;
    Path[i] = i;
    cout << "city " << i << " is at (" << city_location[i][0] << "," << city_location[i][1] << ")\n";
  }

   cout << "\nThe initial path is (";

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
        cout << Path[i]<< " ";
   }
    cout<< Path[0] <<")"<<endl;

//pathdistance(Path, n, distance());

}

double distance(int i, int j) const
{
  double dx = city_location[i][0] - city_location[j][0];
  double dy = city_location[i][1] - city_location[j][1];
  return sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
}
```

Everything works fine up until this point but I have no idea how to pass the distance function/ city_location to the total distance function. Which calculates points pairwise in the order defined by Path[n].

```
    double pathdistance(double Path,int n, double distance())     // Problem lies here, have tried with city_location and *city_location etc but can't figure it out.
{
    //cout<< city_location[0][1];
    double total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n-1;i++)
    {
       total += distance(Path[i],Path[i+1]);         \\Line 63

    }
        total += distance(Path[n],Path[0]);

        cout << "total distance is "<< total<<endl;
        return total;
     }

 };



 int main()
 {
   srand(1235);

   Map<Flat> x(10);
   // Map<Flat> x(10);

   cout << "distance between cities 3 and 7 is " << x.distance(3,7) << "\n";
 }
```

I get the following error:

```
 line 63: invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve the problem? Or potentially an easier way to go about what i'm trying to do with the total distance? Thanks

Comment: Within `pathdistance`, `Path` is not an array, but you're using it like one. `distance` is not a function with two parameters, but you're using it like one.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @chris, but I don't get it, is Path not an array of size n ?

Comment: @Serfempo, It is inside the constructor, where it's declared as such (although the size must be a compile-time constant). It is not inside `pathdistance`, where it is declared `double Path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `path` declaration is `double path` which means a **single** value of type double, not an array.

For passing an array, you can pass it as `double *path` and access the elements via indexing or pass a `std::vector<double>` (a const reference if your function does not change the vector elements).

```
double pathDistance(double *Path, unsigned int n) // first one.

double pathDistance(const std::vector<double>& Path) // second alternative.
```